# Why when opening in edit mode, the el-select component of element-ui only shows me the id (FK) and not the label?

Tags: javascript, rest, vuejs2, element-ui

Why when opening in edit mode, the el-select component of element-ui only shows me the id (FK) and not the label?

I am using php laravel 7 with vuejs 2 and element ui for an application.
The problem I have is when performing a raw, specifically at the time of editing.

When I use el-select to fill data from another table (FK), everything works normal, but at the time of editing, only the "id" of the other table appears, not the label.

I saw in another example and it works perfectly, what could be my mistake?

1. The result of the api is:

```html
{
   "data":[
      {
         "id":17,
         "path":"Perifericos"
      },
      {
         "id":26,
         "path":"Perifericos/Almacenamiento"
      }
   ]
}
```

2. code of vue@2.6.10 with element-ui

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<template>
  <div class="app-container">
    <el-row :gutter="20">
      <el-col :md="16">
        <el-card v-loading="loading" class="box-card">
          <div slot="header" class="clearfix">
            <strong>{{ titleText }}</strong>
          </div>
          <el-form
            ref="Form"
            label-position="left"
            :model="Form"
          >
            <div>
              <el-row :gutter="20">
                <el-col :md="16">
                  <el-form-item label="Nombre" prop="nombre">
                    <el-input v-model="Form.nombre" size="large" />
                  </el-form-item>
                </el-col>
              </el-row>
            </div>
            <el-col :md="8">
              <el-form-item label="Categoriax">
                <el-select v-model="Form.product_ecommerce_menufilter_id" placeholder="Selecciona empresa...">
                  <el-option
                    v-for="emp in categoryProducts"
                    :key="emp.id"
                    :label="emp.path"
                    :value="emp.id"
                  />
                </el-select>
              </el-form-item>
            </el-col>
          </el-form>
        </el-card>
      </el-col>
    </el-row>
  </div>
  <!-- /.app-container -->
</template>
<script>
import ProductResource from '@/api/product';
// import UploadImage from '@/views/components/UploadImage';
const Resource = new ProductResource();
import { get } from '../../api/api';

export default {
  // components: { UploadImage },
  data() {
    return {
      id: null,
      mode: null,
      loading: true,
      titleText: '',
      categoryProducts: [],
      product_ecommerce_menufilter_id: '',
      Form: {},
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.mode = this.$route.meta.mode;
    this.titleText = this.$route.meta.title;
    this.getProductCategoryPath();
    if (this.mode === 'edit') {
      this.id = this.$route.params.id;
      Resource.get(this.id).then(response => {
        this.Form = response.data;
        this.Form.product_ecommerce_menufilter_id = response.data.product_ecommerce_menufilter_id + '';
        this.loading = false;
      });
    } else {
      this.loading = false;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getProductCategoryPath() {
      get('api/products/catalogpathecommerce')
        .then(res => {
          if (res.data) {
            this.categoryProducts = res.data.data;
          }
        })
        .catch(error => {
          this.$message({ type: 'error', message: 'Error al cargar Empresas, consulte al Administrador' });
          console.log(error);
        });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3bSH.png)

Comment: the api loads correctly and also "completing the code" saves in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The v-model in the select and the key of the options have to be from the same type else it doesn't work.

In your case `product_ecommerce_menufilter_id` is a `string` and 'emp.id' is an `int`.

So to fix it you change this:

```
this.Form.product_ecommerce_menufilter_id = response.data.product_ecommerce_menufilter_id + '';
```

into (assuming product_ecommerce_menufilter_id is stored as an int)

```
this.Form.product_ecommerce_menufilter_id = response.data.product_ecommerce_menufilter_id;
```

Here is an example https://codepen.io/reijnemans/pen/gOPMNWw